# How to get CKeditor to switch from Hspace and Vspace to proper CSS

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, ckeditor

I'm working with CKeditor, and for whatever reason, they included Hspace and Vspace in their UI. Convenient idea to allow users to manipulate their images like so, but those are way deprecated.

Has anyone converted CKeditor's Hspace and Vspace to CSS, and know how to explain its conversion?

I am a javascript novice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hspace` and `vspace` are margins in pixels.  The conversion should be direct, immediate and simple.

Where do you want the correction to take place?  I don't know anything about CKEditor's source, so that leads me to propose three options.

Option 1: Replace the `hspace` and `vspace` attributes with proper CSS *at submit time*.  This might impact editability later.

Option 2: Replace the `hspace` and `vspace` attributes with proper CSS *at render time*.  This might be slow if you do it the right way (HTML parser).

Option 3: Replace the `hspace` and `vspace` attributes with proper CSS *on the client side* at render time.  This should be trivial in jQuery, Prototype, Mootools, or whatever library you're using.

---

jQuery to the rescue!  Something like this could work.

```
$('img[hspace]').each(function(el){
    var pixels = parseInt($(el).attr('hspace'));
    if(isNaN(pixels) || pixels < 1)
        pixels = 0;
    else
        pixels = pixels / 2
    $(el).css('marginLeft', pixels + 'px')
         .css('marginRight', pixels + 'px')
         .removeAttr('hspace');
});

$('img[vspace]').each(function(el){
    var pixels = parseInt($(el).attr('vspace'));
    if(isNaN(pixels) || pixels < 1)
        pixels = 0;
    else
        pixels = pixels / 2
    $(el).css('marginTop', pixels + 'px')
         .css('marginBottom', pixels + 'px')
         .removeAttr('vspace');
});
```

Comment: Right, 1 and 2 seem rediculous for CKeditor. Their code is a mess. And the third one is great, but not trivial. I can't imagine how you could do that easily in jquery without regex

Comment: @Trip: Regex?  You don't need no steenking regex!  Updated with some jQuery magic that is totally untested but should work.

Comment: Where is the button to select someone as God? I've looked up and down stackoverflow and can't find it

Comment: If I remove the loop statement it works on one elem. But with it something breaks. Haha, your the best regardless

Comment: Hm.  Well, as I said it's untested.  If you can't get it figured out, please post a follow-up question, there are lots of wizards around to help.

Answer (score 1):

What version of CKEditor are you using?
Load http://ckeditor.com/demo and look at the generated source for that image:
 style="**margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;** float: left; width: 120px; height: 168px;" so you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Interesting.. I just got this a few months ago and it looks like they havn't updated it since. Thanks for the info.